# Is there a real performance gain when I turn {$IMPORTEDDATA} off?

Tags: performance, delphi, memory, delphi-7, delphi-xe

Is there a real performance gain when I turn {$IMPORTEDDATA} off ?

The [manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Imported_data) only says this: "The {$G-} directive disables creation of imported data references. Using {$G-} increases memory-access efficiency, but prevents a packaged unit where it occurs from referencing variables in other packages."

---

Update:

Here is more info I could find:

"The Debugging section has the new option Use imported data references (mapped to $G), which 
controls the creation of imported data references (increasing memory efficiency but preventing the 
access of global variables defined in other runtime packages)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Almost never**

This directive only refers to accessing global unit variables from another unit.

If you use {$G+}

```
unit1;

interface

var
  Global1: integer;   //<--  this is a global var in unit1.
  Form1: TForm1;      //<--  also a global var, but really a pointer
```

`Global1` will be accessed **indirectly** via a pointer *(if and when accessed from outside unit1)*
`Form1` will also be accessed indirectly (i.e. change from a direct pointer to an indirect pointer).

if you use {$G-}, the access to integer `global` will be direct and thus slightly faster.

This will only make a difference if you use global public unit variables in another unit and in time critical code, i.e. almost never.

See this article: http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2006/09/hack13-access-globals-faster.html

Comment: Form1 will also be accessed indirectly. Both Global1 and Form1 are 4 bytes of data contained in memory. Accessing those 4 bytes of data is done the same way whether the content of those 4 bytes represent an integer or a pointer.

Comment: @Ken have you confirmed this yourself?

Comment: I need to admit I did not, as it would go against everything I know on the subject, I assumed it.  I tested it just now for the sake of it and I confirm a form variable is accessed indirectly. The fact that the variable is a pointer doesn't change the fact that you need to access the address where the pointer is stored to read it.  Variable are always accessed "by address". The reason for the indirection here is, when the variable is stored in a package, the is no way for the exe code to know at which address the package (and thus, the variable) will be stored.